# Why does the error of this command not end in the given file? ls -yz 2>&1 >> command.log

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

This page (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) explains (towards the end) why this command:

`ls -yz 2>&1 >> command.log`

does not output the errors into the `command.log` file.

However, it still isn't clear for me. If `2>&1` is redirecting `stderr` to `stdout` then doesn't `>>` just take the results of `stdout` and append them to `command.log`?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, note that `>log` is a short-hand for `1>log`.
The `N>M` syntax translates to pointer reassignments.
Let's call the pointer to standard output `fd1`, and the pointer to standard error `fd2`. That is:

- `fd1` is a pointer to `stdout`
- `fd2` is a pointer to `stderr`

When you execute `cmd 2>&1 >log`, it changes the pointers like this:

- make `fd2` point to what `fd1` points to, which is `stdout`
- make `fd1` point to a file
- => as a result, `fd2` points to `stdout` and `fd1` points to a file

When you execute `cmd >log 2>&1`, it changes the pointers like this:

- make `fd1` point to a file
- make `fd2` point to what `fd1` points to, which is the file
- => as a result, both `fd1` and `fd2` point to the same file

That is, based on the ordering of the pointer reassignments, the outcome will be different. In one case both pointers will be pointing at the same thing, or they will be pointing at different things.

Instead of using `ls -yz` as the example command `cmd`, I find a more suitable example to explain this is `ls yes nonexistent`, where `yes` is a file that exists, and `nonexistent` is a file that doesn't. With this example, there will be something printed on both `stdout` and `stderr`, and by playing with the ordering of `N>M`, you can observe more clearly where each ended up. (With `ls -yz`, there is only `stderr`, while `stdout` is empty.)

Comment: Very well explained!

Answer (score 1):

With redirections, order matters.  Do it the other way around.

```
ls -yz >>command.log 2>&1
```

Redirections work by "copying file descriptors".  If you try redirecting stderr first (before redirecting stdout), then stderr will be sent to where stdout is **currently** going, which is the terminal.  When you later redirect stdout to your file, this does not go back to redirect stderr once more.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate an explanation to the downvote, as if my answer is not the right one, I will learn something here.

Comment: I think OP knows that the order matters, the question is "why" it matters. Note that the two orderings are shown side by side on the page linked by OP, so this much is quite clear.

Answer (score 1):

By default both stdout & stderr are directed to the terminal.  In the command in your question, `2>&1` tells shell to send stderr to the same place as stdout. It's like a no-op because stdout at that point is still going to the terminal, same place as stderr.  `>> command.log` gets parsed after that and ends up sending only stdout to that file.  The order matters, as @Fred rightly says.

Shorter way to do this is:

```
ls -yz &>> command.log
```